# Infinite dimensional dual space vs finite dimension

Tags: linear-algebra

I just have a question about why some of the theorems involving dual space fails for infinite dimension.
A standard problem is below:

"Suppose V is finite-dimensional and v is an element of V with v does not equal 0. Prove that there exists an element in the dual space of V such that phi(v)=1"

The answer is to extend v to a basis of V, then we have a corresponding basis for V'(V' is the dual space of V) and by definition, phi1(v)=1 and 0 for all the other basis of V. So why does the question requires V to be finite dimension? Could we not do the same if V was infinite dimensional?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The argument works fine in infinite dimensions except that you need the axiom of choice to guarantee that infinite-dimensional vector spaces have bases, and in fact "every vector space has a basis" is equivalent to the axiom of choice; this is due to [Blass](http://www.math.lsa.umich.edu/~ablass/bases-AC.pdf).

In the finite-dimensional case this is true in ZF and it's not necessary to get into the set-theoretic weeds like this.

Here is a nice relatively explicit example: $\mathbb{R}$ is an infinite-dimensional vector space over $\mathbb{Q}$. Can you write down any nonzero linear functional $\mathbb{R} \to \mathbb{Q}$ whatsoever? In fact [it's consistent with ZF that there don't exist any](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/49388/is-the-non-triviality-of-the-algebraic-dual-of-an-infinite-dimensional-vector-sp), and any such linear functional must be non-measurable.